# Schwartz–Zippel lemma tight bound

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

As we know by Schwartz–Zippel lemma for $p\in F[x_1 , x_2 , ... , x_n] $ of degree $d$ over a finite field $F$ and for $ r_1,r_2,...,r_n $ uniformly samples from it:

$Pr[P(r_1,...,r_n) = 0 ] \le \frac d {|F|}$

It would be an interesting question to ask how tight is this bound?

Is it the lowest upper bound possible? meaning, foreach $d\le |F|-1$ and $n\in N$, is there a polynomial of degree d with exactly d zeros?

Comment: What is $d$ in your first inequality?

Comment: It's certainly sharp in the one-variable case: take $P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^d(x-a_i)$ for distinct $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_d\in F$.

Comment: Updated to clarify d. And for Carl’s answer, if it’s correct in the one variable case it applies to the general case if you just ignore the other variables, so that is the answer no?

Comment: What Carl and you say is correct, and Schwartz-Zippel is more generally tight for certain types of polynomials (ones that can be written as products of linear polynomials, though there are small correction terms in general). Such polynomials are somewhat atypical though. After all, we expect the values of $p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ to be more or less uniformly distributed, and hence vanish with probability roughly $1/|F|$ more or less irrespective of the degree. But to achieve that we need some information about the factors of $p$.

Comment: For example if we know that a two variable polynomial $p(x,y)$ of degree $d$ is absolutely irreducible (i.e. irreducible over the algebraic closure of $F$), then geometric properties of the curve defined by the zero loci come to the fore, and we do get a better upper bound for the vanishing probability. Like $1/|F|+R_d$, where the correction term $R_d$ does depend on $d$, and is of the size $\mathcal{O}(d^2/|F|^{3/2})$.